# Custom font not connecting on mobile

Tags: css, font-face

I'm using a custom font on my webpage and it works fine on the desktop version, but on mobile devices, the font doesn't change. I think I must be doing something wrong with the font-face property. Here is the CSS file. Any ideas?

```
html, body {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }

body {
  background-image: url("/images/Portrait.jpg");
  font-family: Occupied,Arial,sans-seriff;
}


@font-face {
  font-family:"Occupied";
  src: url("/public/font/Occupied.eot?") format("eot"),
       url("/public/font/Occupied.woff") format("woff"),
       url("/public/font/Occupied.otf") format("otf"),
       url("/public/font/Occupied.woff2") format("woff2"),
       url("/public/font/Occupied.ttf") format("truetype"), 
       url("/public/font/Occupied.svg#Occupied") format("svg");
  font-weight:normal;
  font-style:normal;
}
```

Comment: The correct spelling (in `font-family`) is "sans-serif" (not "seriff") - maybe that causes the problem

Answer (score 1):

Try adding @font-face first

```
@font-face {
  font-family:"Occupied";
  src: url("/public/font/Occupied.eot?") format("eot"),
       url("/public/font/Occupied.woff") format("woff"),
       url("/public/font/Occupied.otf") format("otf"),
       url("/public/font/Occupied.woff2") format("woff2"),
       url("/public/font/Occupied.ttf") format("truetype"), 
       url("/public/font/Occupied.svg#Occupied") format("svg");
  font-weight:normal;
  font-style:normal;
}

html, body {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }

body {
  background-image: url("/images/Portrait.jpg");
  font-family: Occupied,Arial,sans-seriff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/) article on csstricks.com website. there they have clearly mentioned that, 
The `@font-face` rule should be added to the stylesheet before any styles.

additionally, the CSS is executed line by line. when It wants finding a font which is not defined yet it fallbacks to the default font. in this case, it's `sans-seriff` which should be corrected as `sans-serif`. some browsers are smart enough to detect those kind small mistakes and correct them. But It is not guaranteed by every browser.